# printWriter() in servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, web

I have servlet to retrieve image from an oracle database inside `doGet()` and it works fine but when using `printwriter()` the code does not work.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
     response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

     String id = request.getParameter("submit");
    try {

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "APP_DB", "1234");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select photo from photos where id = ?");
        ps.setString(1, id);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        Blob b = rs.getBlob("photo");
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        response.setContentLength((int) b.length());
        InputStream is = b.getBinaryStream();
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        byte buf[] = new byte[(int) b.length()];
        is.read(buf);
        os.write(buf);
         os.close();
        out.print("<a href='DisplyExcServlet'>visit</a>");//does not work            

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the 'does not work' part.

Answer (score 1):

It is illegal to use both `getServletOutputStream()` and `getWriter()` in the same call. You should use only one.

This is what Java Doc says :

> ### getOutputStream...
>
> #### ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException
>
> Returns a ServletOutputStream suitable for writing binary data in the response.
>       The servlet container does not encode the binary data.
>
> Calling flush() on the ServletOutputStream commits the response. 
>      Either this method or getWriter() may be called to write the body, not both.
>
> Returns: a ServletOutputStream for writing binary data 
>     **Throws: IllegalStateException - if the getWriter method has been called on this response**

Answer (score 0):

You must no close the outputstream when you want to do further writing to it. change

```
    os.close();
    out.print("<a href='DisplyExcServlet'>visit</a>");
```

to

```
    out.print("<a href='DisplyExcServlet'>visit</a>");
    os.close(); // now you can close it ^^
```

and it should work.